# Using BASH, how do I remove @Ignore from Java perf tests?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, cygwin

I'm on cygwin.

I want to be able to toggle my perf tests off and on.

This works fine to **insert** `@Ignore`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.java" | xargs sed -i "s/\@Perf/\@Ignore\n\@Perf/g"
```

...**problem** is that the opposite does not work:

```
find . -type f -name "*.java" | xargs sed -i "s/\@Ignore\n\@Perf/\@Perf/g"
```

It could be that the line endings aren't what I think they are or that sed is stopping at the end of the line.

Have also tried:

```
find . -type f -name "*.java" | xargs sed -i "s/\@Ignore\s*\@Perf/\@Perf/g"
find . -type f -name "*.java" | xargs sed -i "s/\@Ignore\s\s\@Perf/\@Perf/g"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) (`\n` better support) :

```
perl -i -0pe "s|\@Ignore\n\@Perf|@Perf|g" file.java
```

And you can choose the substitution delimiter, so by example with `|` :

```
's|before|after|g'
```

Comment: I don't know the first thing about perl and now isn't a good time to learn, I'm afraid. Exactly as presented, this line did not work.

Comment: OIC: Something more like this old line I found:
find ${1} -name test*.properties | xargs perl -i -pe 's/^(dataSource(?:.host))=.*/$1='${2}/

Comment: You have to replace your sed commands with mines, I didn't copy all of your code as you can see. The substitution syntax is exactly the same

Comment: This did not work:
find . -type f -name "*.java" | xargs perl -i -pe "s/\@Ignore\n\@Perf/\@Perf/g"
...nor did this:
 find . -type f -name "*.java" | xargs perl -i -pe "s/\@Ignore\s*\@Perf/\@Perf/g"

Comment: Is there an error ? If it works with sed, it should work with perl too

Comment: Doesn't work with either. No error but boat loads of *.bak files in my dir now. :-/

Comment: You forgot to set a different paragraph delimiter. In the absence of something like `perl -00` the default behavior of `-p` is identical to that of `sed`, i.e. Perl reads a single line at a time.

Comment: Thanks tripleee, post edited accordingly. That's why I asked sample input, it's better to understand and test

Answer (score 1):

**For `sed`**

Just append a next row to pattern matching. Example:

```
# java source file
$ cat foo.java
@Ignore
@Perf
public static int main() {
    return 0;
}

$ sed  "{ N; s/\@Ignore\n\@Perf/\@Perf/g }" foo.java
@Perf
public static int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The `N` command appends the next line to the pattern space (thus ensuring it contains two consecutive lines in every cycle).

Comment: This gets you the match but doesn't replace anything except what is on the current line. In other words it removes (at)Perf, which we want to keep and leaves (at)Ignore, which we are trying to remove.

Comment: @user447607, lol, ok, if it so hard to you to change last `Perf` to `Ignore`, so don't use in my solution(`sed  "{ N; s/\@Ignore\n\@Perf/\@Ignore/g }"`) :)))))

Comment: It's not that it's hard, it's that I have lots of other things to do that I get paid for. ;-)

Comment: @user447607, it would be nice if you will modify our question, because your question actually defines opposite: `... | xargs sed -i "s/\@Ignore\n\@Perf/\@Perf/g"` - means remove `@Ignore` and leave `@Perf`, so I did it as described in question by `regex`.

Comment: That's because we are talking about doing it (1) and then undoing it (2) rather than two different ways to do the same thing. It's undoing it that is causing me trouble.

Comment: Re-read my comment also. Your example removes only what is on the current line even though it matches what was on the previous line AND the current line. sed and it's line endings again. That's behavior I've tested.  I thought your idea would work also. sed had other plans.